# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference

I have a fragment in which I have an image which acts like a swipe to dismiss, when this action happens I have to go back.
And below is the code I have for this.

BaseFragment.kt

```
fun goBack() {
    if (activity is BaseActivity<*>) (activity as BaseActivity<*>).goBack()
}
```

BaseActivity.kt

```
open fun goBack() = onBackPressed()

@CallSuper
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0)
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
    else super.onBackPressed()
}
```

In the above case, the call always goes to super.onBackPressed(). Everything works fine in local and for the majority of the users in the production. However for some users when super.onBackPressed() gets called it throws above NPE.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: Also: You should really be using support library androidx fragments rather than the unmaintained and obsolete android.app fragments.

Comment: (Based on seeing `android.app.FragmentHostCallback` there.)